# Display notice on WooCommerce emails depending on chosen shipping option

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I need to display a specific notice on the `/emails/customer-processing-order.php` email template in WooCommerce depending on the chosen shipping option. Is there a way to check the chosen shipping option and return a note depending on that?

Answer (score 0):

@Jonathan,

> Is there a way to check the chosen shipping option and return a note depending on that

The `WooCommerce Orders` are stored in the `woocommerce_orders` table in WordPress.

I would start by placing an example order, and searching for the `order number` and `post_id` in the database to find the correct fields.

The `post_id` can be seen in the `url` field.